# Text selection breaks scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying out iOS 15 with Xcode Beta 2, and I'm using the new [textSelection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/textselection(_:)) feature for `Text`.

However, if you enable text selection and put the `Text` objects in a `List`, and try scrolling on the text, nothing happens. However, disabling the text selection allows scrolling anywhere on the list.

Here is some reproducible code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data = (0..<100).map { "Test: \($0)" }
    var body: some View {
        List(data, id: \.self) { str in
            Text(str)
                .textSelection(.enabled)
        }
    }
}
```

If you try scrolling by moving your finger up on the area **with** text, nothing happens. However you can still scroll on the white areas.

Disabling text selection fixes this issue.

Are there any possible workarounds?

Comment: I can confirm. A Bug report is probably a good approach for this. It doesn’t seem to be user friendly.